# Using Bootstrap as a custom toolbar button in Froala Editor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, froala

I'm in a bit of a pickle - and as a newer Stack Overflow user, I'm hoping I am posting this in the right place.

I am currently tinkering with [Froala Editor](https://editor.froala.com/) and have been learning quite a bit. When I started checking out the documentation and delving a bit more into it, however, I'm having some trouble integrating Bootstrap.

Basically, I want it so that when an action is triggered, a pre-created "block" is inserted into the Editor. I have no problem with this functionality, but my problem begins when the content of that block doesn't display correctly.

To create the custom block trigger, I integrate `var widget` in the JS (formatted for better readability):

```
widget = '<a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Bootstrap Works!</a><br>
         <div class="container-fluid">

             <div class="row">

                 <div class="col-xs-6" style="background:yellow;">
                     <h2>Title One</h2>
                     <img src="http://placehold.it/140x140" class="img-circle img-responsive">
                 </div>

                 <div class="col-xs-6" style="background:red;">
                     <h2>Title Two</h2>
                     <img src="http://placehold.it/140x140" class="img-circle img-responsive">
                 </div>

             </div>

         </div>';
```

Select "first widget" (default option) and click "Add Widget." Everything works as intended - except two `col-xs-6`'s stack on top of each other instead of floating into columns as it typically would.

View an example here:
http://nyit.me/wysiwyg/5-cstm/2.php

I have tried adjusting `.container` and `.container-fluid`, adjusting some custom settings within Froala (including `padding: 0;` and `margin: 0;`), and adjusting basic `body` and `html` CSS, but nothing seems to work. Ultimately, I have the feeling I'm missing something super simple and completely over-thinking this.

Thanks for any advice!

z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing is related to `box-sizing`. There is a [commit](https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor/commit/2be4703789714351e86aa1c534535d26e1c1fc63) on Github that should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It appears I am already on that commit version, though?

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. The commit worked. Thanks so much!